# What is GenCollectForAllocation means?

Tags: java, profile, jfr

While reading a JFR dump, I came up with a VM Operation called `GenCollectForAllocation` that is taking more time than other processes. Can anyone explain to me what this operation is?

[image: Java Mission Control Snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason of why a safepoint was triggered ([there are many of them](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/runtime/vmOperations.hpp#l64)). You can read it as : "a **gen**erational **collect**or just had an **allocation** failure", as such a *safepoint* will be triggered so that the application is stopped (stop-the-world event).

It seems these are cumulative times, so a *total* sum of all times is added; considering that minor GC happens a lot and if your application is running for a long time - this is not really a problem. You also had `223` of such events, with the *longest* duration of `305 ms`, but on average (`9.786 / 223`): `43ms`. That is a healthy figure, IMHO.